# How do I change the text size and component width of a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the following code to create a UIPickerView:

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 416.0f - height, 320.0f, height)];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[pickerView setSoundsEnabled:YES];
```

I would like to change the component widths and change the text size in each component. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can change the width by an appropriate delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    switch(component) {
        case 0: return 22;
        case 1: return 44;
        case 2: return 88;
        default: return 22;
    }

    //NOT REACHED
    return 22;
}
```

As for a custom text size, you can use the delegate to return custom views with whatever sized text you want:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
        UILabel *retval = (id)view;
        if (!retval) {
            retval= [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] autorelease];
        }

        retval.text = @"Demo";
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
        return retval;
}
```

Of course you will need modify these to have appropriate values for your app, but it should get you where you need to go.

Comment: A couple of errors in your second code block:

 - The UIView needs to be cast to (UILabel*).
 - The retval assignment line is missing an opening bracket and needs to call initWithFrame otherwise we'll get nothing displayed:

ie.

 retval = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] autorelease];

Comment: Thanks, I'll make appropriate changes, though not exactly what you propose. I am going to cast through an id, basically because it is shorter and you don't give anything up because the lval of the expression is already typed to a UIView.

Comment: I also want to add this line to the answer in case you are working with an array to populate the picker (most likely). Instead of retval.text = @"Demo", replace with retval.text = [messageArray objectAtIndex:row];