# Changing text size in Pickerview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How can we change the size of the text in a picker view?

Anyone please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the text size and component width of a UIPickerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256556/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-and-component-width-of-a-uipickerview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the font size of UIPickerView using code :

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
            UILabel *retval = (id)view;
            if (!retval) {
                retval= [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] autorelease];
            }

            retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];

       return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, yakub_moriss code lacks of one line, which was in the post signaled by indragie. Without a line as

```
retval.text = [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

the picker will be empty.

Comment: Hey Luca had one doubt in this concept.Actually my array is arr1 .So accordingly I have set retval.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:row];but im getting error like this Program received signal SIGABRT  at that particular line.My pickerView is like this pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init] ;
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 75, 200, 150);
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES; and for label size I m adding the same code as Yakub have said..Can u please tell me y ?

Answer (score 3):

This is also a great way to change the alignment of the text in the component too, change the textAlignment of the retval label.

Also, the background for the label should be set to clear:

```
    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {
        UILabel *retval = (id)view;
        if (!retval) {
            retval = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 
                      [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, 
                      [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        }
        retval.opaque = NO;
        retval.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:28];
        if (component == 0) {
            retval.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            retval.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", row];
        } else {
            retval.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            retval.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" .%d", row];
        }
        return retval;
    }

    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        if (component == 0) { 
            return 100;
        }
        return 88;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a category for this. It relies on this other category I have: http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2012/06/adding-properties-to-class-you-dont.html.

Anyway, this one looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIPickerView (CustomViewForRow)

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIFont *customViewForRowFont;

- (UIView *)customViewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "UIPickerView+CustomViewForRow.h"
#import "NSObject+AssociatedObjectSupport.h"

@implementation UIPickerView (CustomViewForRow)


static char keyForCustomViewForRowFont;
- (UIFont *)customViewForRowFont {
    UIFont *retVal = [self associatedObject:&keyForCustomViewForRowFont];
    if (!retVal)
        retVal = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    return retVal;
}

- (void)setCustomViewForRowFont:(UIFont *)customViewForRowFont {
    [self setAssociatedObject:customViewForRowFont forKey:&keyForCustomViewForRowFont];
}

- (UIView *)customViewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *label;
    if (!view) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
        frame.size = [self rowSizeForComponent:component];
        view.frame = frame;
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.font = self.customViewForRowFont;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        frame = view.bounds;
        frame.origin.x += 7;
        frame.size.width -= 14;
        label.frame = frame;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }

    label = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    @try {
        NSString *text = [self.delegate pickerView:self titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
        if (!text)
            text = @"???";
        label.text = text;
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
        label.text = @"???";
    }

    return view;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
https://github.com/kafejo/CCPicker
it's very easy picker :)