# How can I get the row number of each components in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

How can I get the row number of each component in `UIPickerView`?

I Have `UIPickerView` Whit 3 components:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

And The second question is How can I change width of each component?

Comment: do you mean, how many rows are in each component?

Comment: I think you usually decide it through your data source, isn't it?

Comment: no i mean what row is selected in each component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably populating the UIPickerView from an array; use the `row` parameter in a call to

```
[dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

to get the data. If you need to know the total number of rows, just use `[dataArray count];` to get the size of your data source.

EDIT: I forgot that if you're following the protocol, you'll have implemented this method:

```
-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSInteger numRows = 0;
    switch (component) {
    case 0:
        numRows = 6;
        break;
    case 1:
        numRows = 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        numRows = 2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return numRows;
}
```

So, you're actually telling the system how many rows for each component. Check this, or go ahead and implement it, and you'll have your answer!

EDIT 2: if you want to get the current selected row in each component, use:

```
[yourPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
```

as many times as you need. I suggest looping through all components and using this method to get the selected row.

Comment: if i use this i have the all UIPickerView rows in all components

Comment: remember i want number of row in each component not all of them

Comment: i actually want to create a uipickeview like uidatepicker "" in uidatepicker when u select the component's row the uidatepicker returns the number of row in each component to submit that

Comment: okay, one more edit, that should be what you're looking for. The UIPickerView documentation has all this info, by the way.

Comment: i have warning: local declaration of 'pickerView' hides instance variable in use [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]

Comment: that's because you're probably trying to call it from within one of the other methods, where pickerView is supplied as a parameter. Try using self.pickerView, instead of pickerView. Did I answer your question?

Comment: when i use self [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] i have error: accessing unknown 'pickerView' getter method

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question... you need to actually have a pickerView property, and include @synthesize pickerView in your implementation. When you created your pickerView, you need to assign it to an instance variable.

Comment: And The second question is How can I Change Width of Each component?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256556/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-and-component-width-of-a-uipickerview