# Is that possible to change the font size of UIPickerView in UIWebView?

Tags: fonts, uiwebview, size, uipickerview

Is that possible to change the font size of UIPickerView in UIWebView?

Comment: A "UIPickerView in UIWebView"? Presume you just mean a UIPickerView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the text size and component width of a UIPickerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256556/how-do-i-change-the-text-size-and-component-width-of-a-uipickerview)

Comment: @middaparka I think the question is referring to the `UIPickerView` that comes up when you focus on a `<select>` "drop down" in a UIWebView.