# What is the default font name and size for UIPickerview picker values in iOS 7 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios7, ios6

How to get the default  font name and size for UIPickerview picker values in iOS 7 and iOS 6.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185440/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-uipickerview) question, to know how to access the labels in `UIPickerView`. From there, you can get it's font easily.

Comment: Can you explain your goal?

Comment: @n00bprogrammer , ur link is not helpful. In ur link, we need define not to get what font used.

Comment: @Rashad, i am customizing the pickerview , but i want to set the same font name and size for iOS 7 and iOS 6.

Comment: @sehaswaranmayilerum,  If your goal is just creating pickerview with current font name and size means, what is the need of getting that details. Just add pickerview, this pickerview will take default fontname and size.

Comment: @Ramdy i am not just creating pickerview. i am customizing.

Comment: ok even your customizing with default font name and size, you don't need to get that details.

Comment: @Ramdy ok. fine. We don't need get . But, Do u know how to get those details?

Comment: ya tried to get, but failded . @sehaswaranmayilerum

Comment: Default is set to system font as I know.

Comment: @Rashad Thanks. Do you have any idea on font size?

Comment: @Sehaswaranmayilerum > Most probably 17, not sure about this.

Comment: @Rashad Ok. thanks. Is 17 works for both iOS 7 and iOS 6.

Comment: I don't think that there should be any problem in you set 17 for both iOS 6 & 7.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 10.3, iPhone and iPad, the default UIPickerView font is:

> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay"; font-weight:
>   normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 21.00pt

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @BallpointBen, I found this in Xcode while was exploring UIPickerView subviews with Debug View Hierarchy tool. Try it.

Comment: You may get this by running:  
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
            print(font)

Comment: @JoeGalind I like this approach, but .largeTitle is much too large for UIPickerView. .title2 looks closer.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 12 the font used for the centered component as displayed seems to be `San Francisco Display (SystemFont)` with weight `Regular` and size `23.5`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below show default font detail and size. I simple made a demo to check for your answer and code is below :-

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text =@"testRr";
    NSLog(@"%@",[label font]);
    return label.text;
}
```

Log print is as below -

[image]

So when you customize your picker it's upto you to pick which font or size you want to use. you could also add your own font-family.

Comment: Hello All, when you vote down for an answer then please provide a comment for doing so. This way all of us could improve ourself regardless of my answer being right or wrong.

Comment: I think people are down voting because your answer shows the font size for a custom label in the UIPickerView not the default used if you the method of just providing strings.


`- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Comment: @Wombat : ok thanks ! Then do u have any solution for that as per me when we use the picker we do pass the label (with/without customisation) so we could check that labels font/size. Pls update me if you know a way. Once again thanks :)