# How to change Picker font size using Xamarin forms ios PickerRenderer?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, picker

For Android i was able to do it this way

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (e.OldElement == null && e.NewElement == null) return;
    Control.TextSize = 14f;
    Control.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex(Constants.Color.SLATE_GRAY).ToAndroid());
}
```

Is there any way for ios using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.ios.PickerRenderer?
I could see an example in ios. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185440/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-uipickerview). But now sure how to convert it into Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking 'Go to Definition' ,you can find `PickerRenderer` inherit `ViewRenderer<Picker, UITextField>`

so we just set `Font` on `Control` , refer to the following code

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if(Control != null)
    {
        Control.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
        Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(30);
    }
}
```