# how to change the font size of picker view in autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

[image]

i am trying to fix the autolayout of my picker view, at the iPhone (compact width and regular height) it seems Okay, but for iPad ( regular width and regular height), it seems the size of the font of my picker view remains the same as the iPhone, I want the font size of my picker view in iPad little bit bigger, I usually add customization for the font size of regular width and regular height, but there is no option to adjust the font size of picker view in the interface builder.

what should I do?

Comment: Changing the font size of a UIPickerView may not be supported using Interface Builder, you can do so directly using code after checking the device type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185440/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-uipickerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can´t be done in the Interface Builder, you need to do it programmatically. It´s kind of easy, do it like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        pickerLabel.text = "Row \(row)"
    } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        pickerLabel.text = "Row \(row)"
    }
    return pickerLabel
}
```

If you´re using `pickerView` `titleForRow` you need to remove that function to be able to use `viewForRow`.